# list index out of range on Keras train_on_batch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a simple matrix called `timeseries`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[6,7,8,9,10]
[1,3,5,7,9]
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

I wanna perform RNN `model.train_on_batch(timeseries[:,0:1], timeseries[:, 1])`,
but it gave me the error `list index out of range`

The network I build is like this

```
model = Sequential()
    if args.layers == 1:
        model.add(LSTM(args.neurons, batch_input_shape=(num_timeseries, 1, num_dims), return_sequences=False, stateful=True))
    else:
        model.add(LSTM(args.neurons, batch_input_shape=(num_timeseries, 1, num_dims), return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
        for i in range(args.layers - 2):
            model.add(LSTM(args.neurons, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
        model.add(LSTM(args.neurons, return_sequences=False, stateful=True))

    num_mixture_components = args.mixture_components
    model.add(Dense((num_dims + 2) * num_mixture_components))
    model.add(GMMActivation(num_mixture_components))
    model.compile(loss=gmm_loss, optimizer=RMSprop(lr=args.learning_rate))
```

The error log is

```
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Optimization failure due to: LocalOptGroup(use_c_ger,use_c_gemv)
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): node: Gemv{no_inplace}(AllocEmpty{dtype='float32'}.0, TensorConstant{1.0}, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, Reshape{1}.0, TensorConstant{0.0})
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): TRACEBACK:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1922, in process_node
    replacements = lopt.transform(node)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1309, in transform
    new_repl = opt.transform(node)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/blas_c.py", line 674, in use_c_gemv
    if not config.blas.ldflags:
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 328, in __get__
    val_str = self.default()
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1258, in default_blas_ldflags
    lib_path = blas_info.get('library_dirs', [])[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Optimization failure due to: LocalOptGroup(use_c_ger,use_c_gemv)
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): node: Gemv{no_inplace}(AllocEmpty{dtype='float32'}.0, TensorConstant{1.0}, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, Reshape{1}.0, TensorConstant{0.0})
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): TRACEBACK:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1922, in process_node
    replacements = lopt.transform(node)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1309, in transform
    new_repl = opt.transform(node)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/blas_c.py", line 674, in use_c_gemv
    if not config.blas.ldflags:
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 328, in __get__
    val_str = self.default()
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1258, in default_blas_ldflags
    lib_path = blas_info.get('library_dirs', [])[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Optimization failure due to: LocalOptGroup(use_c_ger,use_c_gemv)
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): node: Gemv{no_inplace}(AllocEmpty{dtype='float32'}.0, TensorConstant{1.0}, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, Reshape{1}.0, TensorConstant{0.0})
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): TRACEBACK:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1922, in process_node
    replacements = lopt.transform(node)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1309, in transform
    new_repl = opt.transform(node)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/blas_c.py", line 674, in use_c_gemv
    if not config.blas.ldflags:
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 328, in __get__
    val_str = self.default()
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1258, in default_blas_ldflags
    lib_path = blas_info.get('library_dirs', [])[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Optimization failure due to: LocalOptGroup(use_c_ger,use_c_gemv)
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): node: Gemv{no_inplace}(AllocEmpty{dtype='float32'}.0, TensorConstant{1.0}, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, Reshape{1}.0, TensorConstant{0.0})
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): TRACEBACK:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1922, in process_node
    replacements = lopt.transform(node)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1309, in transform
    new_repl = opt.transform(node)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/blas_c.py", line 674, in use_c_gemv
    if not config.blas.ldflags:
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 328, in __get__
    val_str = self.default()
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1258, in default_blas_ldflags
    lib_path = blas_info.get('library_dirs', [])[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Optimization failure due to: Elemwise{sub,no_inplace}(z, Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}(alpha subject to <function <lambda> at 0x10afdb5f0>, SparseDot(x, y))) -> Usmm{no_inplace}(Elemwise{neg,no_inplace}(alpha), x, y, z)
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): node: Elemwise{sub,no_inplace}(Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0, Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0)
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): TRACEBACK:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1922, in process_node
    replacements = lopt.transform(node)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1673, in transform
    self.pdb)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1631, in match
    u = match(p, v, u, self.allow_multiple_clients)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1631, in match
    u = match(p, v, u, self.allow_multiple_clients)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1642, in match
    if constraint(expr):
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sparse/opt.py", line 883, in <lambda>
    theano.config.blas.ldflags)},
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 328, in __get__
    val_str = self.default()
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1258, in default_blas_ldflags
    lib_path = blas_info.get('library_dirs', [])[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RNN_test.py", line 101, in <module>
    results = model.train_on_batch(timeseries[:,i:i+1], timeseries[:, i])
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 712, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1220, in train_on_batch
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 703, in _make_train_function
    **self._function_kwargs)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 727, in function
    return Function(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 713, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function.py", line 326, in function
    output_keys=output_keys)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 486, in pfunc
    output_keys=output_keys)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1784, in orig_function
    defaults)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1651, in create
    input_storage=input_storage_lists, storage_map=storage_map)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 699, in make_thunk
    storage_map=storage_map)[:3]
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/vm.py", line 1057, in make_all
    impl=impl))
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 924, in make_thunk
    no_recycling)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 828, in make_c_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1190, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1131, in __compile__
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1578, in cthunk_factory
    key = self.cmodule_key()
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1268, in cmodule_key
    compile_args=self.compile_args(),
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 944, in compile_args
    ret += x.c_compile_args()
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/blas.py", line 501, in c_compile_args
    return ldflags(libs=False, flags=True)
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/blas.py", line 381, in ldflags
    ldflags_str = theano.config.blas.ldflags
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 328, in __get__
    val_str = self.default()
  File "/Users/LaurenceLuo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1258, in default_blas_ldflags
    lib_path = blas_info.get('library_dirs', [])[0]
IndexError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', Dot22(InplaceDimShuffle{0,x}.0, lstm_1_W_o), '\n', 'list index out of range')
```

Thank you!

Comment: The same thing happened when I use model.fit(). I use Mac OS.

Comment: I think I find the answer. It is due to the length of time series (sequence) parameter you set. It should be in accordance with the actual data.